# How can I change this json structure?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json response which I have got after

```
result = JSON.parse(result.value);
```

json response

```
"{"name":"For ","children":["{ \"name\":\"sxsm cnklsd\"}","{ \"name\":\"smd csdm\"}"]}".
```

Now I am trying to convert this in to a structure as:

```
{
    "name": "For  ",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "sxsm cnklsd"
        },
        {
            "name": "smd csdm"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to double parsing , stringify and then parse but nothing seems to be working. Please help.

Comment: you've got json-embedded-in-json? You should fix whatever's generating the json rather than trying to undo that mess...

Comment: @nicael: `children` is an array that contains a single string, which happens to be embedded json. OP wants to "undo" that embedding.

Comment: That's not a JSON response, that's junk. It's inconsistently quoted.

Comment: Can you put your input to `JSON.parse` in the question? it seems that there is something wrong with it.

Comment: @tadman don't forget the ending dot.

Comment: @tadman: This is likely the `console.log` output. That's what you get when you log a string.

Comment: I have purposely generated it so that I can get a hierarchical json structure.

Comment: Then you don't understand how JSON works. This is a hierarchical json structure: `'{"name":"For ","children":[{ "name":"sxsm cnklsd"},{ "name":"smd csdm"}]}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the JSON as you have done:

```
> result = JSON.parse(result.value);
< {"name":"For ","children":["{ \"name\":\"sxsm cnklsd\"}","{ \"name\":\"smd csdm\"}"]}
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`children` is an array containing two JSON strings. Parse them:

```
> result.children = result.children.map(JSON.parse)
> result
< {"name":"For ", "children":[{ "name":"sxsm cnklsd"}, {"name":"smd csdm"}]}
```